# How do i get the other text from not displaying- decision structures?

Tags: java

I have been trying to find a solution to this but I'm just not getting it. When I input age as `13` and time as `2230` both "Midnight Madness is not available for children under 14 years old!" and the price are output.

In the console:

Please enter your age: [13]

Please enter show time:  [2230]

Midnight Madness is not available for children under 14 years old!The ticket price is $8.00>

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class MovieTickets
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");
        int age;
        int time;

        double price = 8.00;
        double ch = 4.00;

        System.out.print("Please enter your age:");
        age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter show time: ");
        time = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(" ");

        if (age > 13)
            if (time < 1800)
                price = 5.00;
        else if (time > 2200)
            price = 4.00;
        if (age < 14)
        {
            if (time < 1800)
                price = 2.00;
            else if (time > 2200)
                System.out.print("Midnight Madness is not available for children under 14 years old!");
            else
                price = 4.00;
        }
        System.out.print("The ticket price is " + df.format(price));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Your logic clearly states that that is the expected behaviour: `if (age < 14 ) { ... else if (time > 2200) System.out.println(...`.  What would you like to change?

Comment: my problem is that in the compiler when i put age as under 13 and time over 2200 it comes up with the message saying your not allowed to go as you are young but it also displays the price.

Comment: Midnight Madness is not available for children under 14 years old!The ticket price is $8.00>

this happens i just dont need the "The ticket price is $8.00" after the first sentence.